# Подскажите библиотеку типа Shazam для java android (поиск песен)

Tags: java, android

Всем привет, хочу в приложении сделать поиск песен по типу шазама. Существует ли библиотека такая на java для андроид? Нашел типа такого https://github.com/wsieroci/audio-recognizer

Comment: вы собираетесь создать android приложение без бекенда, которое будет индексировать композиции лицензированным алгоритмом прямо на устройстве и после выполнять поиск по таким композициям?

Comment: хотя бы поиск по названию. Чтобы показывало название песни.

Comment: Я думаю, вы не совсем понимаете, что такое Shazam. Это сервис с бэкендом с огромной базой, с обученной ИИ которая может находить все это и отправлять на устройство. Просто так на устройстве это не запустить. Это не какая-то либа

Comment: Ага, вы просто не знаете как работает Shazam. Правильно задайте вопрос, кста