# Подскажите библиотеку типа Shazam для java android (поиск названия песни)

Tags: java, android

Всем привет, хочу в приложении сделать поиск песен по типу шазама. Чтобы выводило хотя бы название песни. Существует ли библиотека такая на java для андроид? Нашел типа такого https://github.com/wsieroci/audio-recognizer

Comment: Про гугл уже даже не пытаетесь вспомнить?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Подскажите библиотеку типа Shazam для java android (поиск песен)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1131972/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-shazam-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-java-android-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bd)

Comment: Не нужно задавать один и тот же вопрос 2 раза. А лучше вообще